# Prevent running the next script if an error occurred

Tags: powershell

How can I prevent the next script from running if there is an error on the previous one?

### Scripts

```
RUNME.ps1: |
        write-Host "Script:" $PSCommandPath;
        write-Host "Path:" $PSScriptRoot;
        write-Host "=====";
        & "$PSScriptRoot/script1.ps1" &&
        & "$PSScriptRoot/script2.ps1" &&
        & "$PSScriptRoot/script3.ps1";

SCRIPT1.ps1: |
        write-host "Hello from Script1" &&
        write-host "Version $($psversiontable.PSVersion)";

SCRIPT2.ps1: |
        write-host "Hello from Script2" &&
        Get-Date -Format ss | %{if ($_ % 2 -eq 0) { write-error "$_ even" } else {write-host "$_ odd" }}

SCRIPT3.ps1: |
        write-host "Hello from Script3" ||
        write-host "Version $($psversiontable.PSVersion)";
```

---

#### Updated

Based on @zett42 answer, I had to update the **Script2** to cover the scenario.  So, I don't want Script3 to run if Script2 fails.

Comment: why not use `-ErrorAction Stop`?

Comment: Would you please elaborate on that with an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible way is to set an exit code different than zero by the script that reports the error:

Script2.ps1:

```
$errCount = $error.Count

write-host "Hello from Script2" &&
Get-Date -Format ss | %{if ($_ % 2 -eq 0) { write-error "$_ even" } else {write-host "$_ odd" }}

# If there are new errors, exit script with an exit code that indicates error    
if( $error.Count -gt $errCount ) { 
    exit 1 
}
```

This works because the `&&` and `||` [pipeline chain operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipeline_chain_operators?view=powershell-7.1) use the `$?` and `$LASTEXITCODE` variables to determine failure.

It is assumed, that `$ErrorActionPreference` is not set to `Stop`. If it were `Stop`, the first command that reported an error would cause a script-terminating error, exiting the script prematurely (before it reaches the `if` condition) and also skipping all following scripts.

Comment: can you explain a little more on that?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala What exactly do you not understand? I have added a link.

Comment: sorry, completely missed that; im a lil drunk.

Comment: Note: && and  || are only available in PS 7+.

Comment: @zeti42, thank you for the prompt response. in your method, it will always exit with code 1, where I most likely want to be able to return it only if an error occurred in the code, and I know that my sample doesn't cover that, but my question does.  Would you please add it to your answer?